# Why is the store did not see action in reflux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flux, refluxjs

I get the following error

> actions.toggleMenu is not a function

I create a action

```
module.exports = Reflux.createAction([
    'callAi',
    'logout',
    'fullScreen',
    'toggleMenu',
    'showSidebar'
]);
```

I create this store

```
actions = require('../actions/menu.js');

module.exports = Reflux.createStore({
    listenables: actions,
    init: function () {
        console.log('init', this)  // Its good!
    },
    onCallAi: function () {},
    onLogout: function () {},
    onFullScreen: function () {},
    onToggleMenu: function () {
        console.log('actions onToggle', 'inMoment') //Not good
    },
    onShowSidebar: function () {}
});
```

And this view

actions = require('../../../../Plus-WRIO-App/js/actions/menu')
store = require('../../../../Plus-WRIO-App/js/stores/menu')

```
var CreateDomLeft = React.createClass({
    mixins: [Reflux.listenTo(store, "log")],
    toggle: function(){
        console.log('toggle', 'GO');
        actions.toggleMenu() // error here!!!
    },
    render: function() {
        return (
           <li onClick={this.toggle}  className='btn btn-link'></li>
        );
    }
});

module.exports = CreateDomLeft;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo. It should be `createActions` (plural)